# SQL Server ,tableau dahsboards

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement to show 6 months data in a Tableau Dashboard. For that I created a view in SQL server which has a join on 3 tables T1,T2 and T3. Each table is having 20 million records and the number will keep on increasing. The problem is that when I execute the query it takes a long time about 2 hours and nothing is displayed on dashboard. Is there a way to increase the performance of the query.

Follwing  is the query for cretaing a view. T1,T2 and T3 are three tables and trackingIdentifier in T1 is the foreign key in T3 as transmissionTID and 
trackingIdentifier in T2 is the foreign key in T3 as claimSubmissionTID and

Indexes are built on trackingIdentifier , transmissionTID, trackingIdentifier.

RAM: 32768 MB
Processors: 32
SQL Version : 11.0.3381.0

```
Create View [dbo].[claimReceivingDashboard] AS 
(
Select 
  trans.trackingIdentifier as trackingIdentifier,
  trans.receiptdt as downloadDate, 
  trans.transactiondate as TransactionDate, 
  trans.purpose as Purpose , 
  trans.recordCount as RecordCount , 
  cast(acv.activityNet as decimal(12,4)) as Net, 
  d.Caption as DispositionID ,
  trans.SenderID as SenderId , 
  trans.transmissionfilename as filename ,
  trans.damaninscomp as ReceiverID,
  claim.claimid as claimid , 
  claim.claimproviderid as providerid , 
  claim.trackingIdentifier as claimTrackingId
from 
  endisposition d , t1 trans ,  t2 acv, t3 claim  
where 
  claim.dispositionId = d.EnumId 
  and trans.trackingIdentifier = acv.transmissionTID 
  and claim.trackingIdentifier = acv.claimsubmissionTID 
  and cast(t1.transationdate as date)  > cast(Getdate() - 120 as date))

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the right attributes between endisposition d, t1, t2 and t3 below is the sample

```
endisposition d inner join t1 trans
on d.joiningcolumn = trans.joiningcolumn
inner join t2 acv
on trans.trackingidentifier = acv.transmissionid
inner<<left depends on the requirement>> join t3 claim
on acv.claimsubmissionid = claim.trackingidentifier
where condition
```

you can avoid condition by calculating this in variable cast(Getdate() - 120 as date))

If these joining conditions are not indexed properly create indexes by looking at execution plan